# Moving an image from center to left onScroll using Animated React Native

Tags: react-native, animation

I have an image at the center and I want to move the image to the left gradually and stop at a point onScrolling the screen. I have done the following till now. But the animated is not working. Here's what I have done:

```js
    export default function ProfileDetailsScreen() {
        const animatedValue = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
        const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
        const translateX = animatedValue.interpolate({ inputRange: [200, 700], outputRange: [200, 700], extrapolateLeft: 'clamp' });

        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.headerView}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Icon name="arrowleft" size={25} color="#24B282" />

                    <View style={styles.rightHeader}>
                        <Icons name="edit" size={25} color="#24B282" />
                        <Icon name="download" size={25} color="#24B282" style={{ marginLeft: 20 }} />
                    </View>
                </View>

                <Animated.View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
                    <View style={[styles.container, { transform: [{ translateX }] }]}>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.profileImage}
                            source={Images.profileImage}
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.nameText}>Luke Williams (EG00032)</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.emailText}>Luke_williams@orangetree.software</Text>
                    </View>

                    <SegmentedButtons
                        value={value}
                        onValueChange={setValue}
                        style={styles.segmentedButton}
                        buttons={[
                            {
                                value: 'one',
                                label: <Text style={value === 'one' ? styles.myLabelSelected : styles.myLabel}>General Profile</Text>,
                                style: {
                                    borderColor: value === 'one' ? '#24B282' : '#EDEDED',
                                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                    borderRightColor: '#24B282',
                                    borderRightWidth: value === 'one' ? 1 : 0,

                                },
                            },
                            {
                                value: 'two',
                                label: <Text style={value === 'two' ? styles.myLabelSelected : styles.myLabel}>Medical Profile</Text>,
                                style: {
                                    borderColor: value === 'two' ? '#24B282' : '#EDEDED',
                                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                    borderRightColor: '#24B282',
                                    borderRightWidth: value === 'two' ? 1 : 0,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                value: 'three',
                                label: <Text style={value === 'three' ? styles.myLabelSelected : styles.myLabel}>Bank & Payroll</Text>,
                                style: {
                                    borderColor: value === 'three' ? '#24B282' : '#EDEDED',
                                    backgroundColor: '#fff'
                                },
                            },
                        ]}
                    />
                    {value === 'one' ?
                        <GeneralDetails />
                        : value === 'two' ?
                            <MedicalDetails />
                            : value === 'three' ?
                                <BankDetails /> : null
                    }
                </Animated.View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
```

Please let me know what can be done here.